# return django model property field in graphene graphql query

Tags: graphene-python, graphene-django

How to add a `@property` field from a django model graphql results?:

```
class MyModel(...):
    ...
    @property
    def some_property(self):
        return 'property here'
```

```
class MyObject(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = []
```

```
query GetMyModel(id: ID!){
    getMyModel(id: $id){
        someProperty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An example by adding the `some_property` field:

```
class MyObject(DjangoObjectType):

    some_property = graphene.String()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        filter_fields = []
```

query:

```
query GetMyModel(id: ID!){
    getMyModel(id: $id){
        someProperty
    }
}
```

input:

```
{"variables": {"id": btoa("MyObject:123")}}
```